# Why does order of elements in a set differ in py2 and py3?

Tags: python, set

In py2:

```
{1: {“1”, “2”, “7”, “3”, “4”, “9”, “8”}}
```

Returns for all runs `{1: set([‘1’, ‘3’, ‘2’, ‘4’, ‘7’, ‘9’, ‘8’])}`

In py3:

```
{1: {“1”, “2”, “7”, “3”, “4”, “9”, “8”}}
```

Returns for first run `{1: {“1”, “3”, “4”, “7”, “8”, “2”, “9”}}`

Returns for second run `{1: {“2”, “4”, “9”, “7”, “1”, “3”, “8”}}`
Order of items in inside dict keeps changing.

My main question is why does it keep changing with every run and how to resolve it so that returns a stable result as in py2?

Comment: That is a set - and sets do not have a reliable order. How to resolve it? By using a list instead.

Comment: @luk2302: Dicts are ordered now, but not sets.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Microsoft visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Use a different structure (like a list or dict (since Python 3.7)/OrderedDict) - sets inherently don't have a concept of order.